# Connect to secure web servive with pfx certificate using python

Tags: python-2.7, ssl, certificate, pfx

Hi i need help to get info from web service on secure site with pfx certificate with password.
i tried more then one example..

code example:

```
import requests
wsdl_url = 'blabla'
requests.get(wsdl_url, cert='cert.pfx', verify=True)
```

other example:

```
import urllib3
import certifi
wsdl_url = 'blabla'
http = urllib3.PoolManager(
    cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED', # Force certificate check.
    ca_certs=certifi.where()  # Path to the Certifi bundle.
)
certifi.where()
# You're ready to make verified HTTPS requests.
try:
    r = http.request('GET', wsdl_url)
    print r
except urllib3.exceptions.SSLError as e:
    print "wrong"
    # Handle incorrect certificate error.
```

Error type:
connection aborted
an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

help please